# Loop for em lista com vários elementos - Python

Tags: python, lista, loop, for

Tenho uma lista com várias tuplas dentro, e dentro das tuplas vários elementos.
Preciso varrer todas as tuplas da lista para capturar um elemento que está dentro de cada uma dessa tuplas. Como posso fazer isso?

A estrutura está abaixo:

Variável criada / Tipo:list / Tamanho: 10
Ao abrir a lista:
Índice: 0 / Tipo: Tuple / Tamanho: 5 -> sendo: 2 Str e 3 Int

Quero capturar um dos dados do tipo Int.

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente usa-se o `for` para iterar em cima de uma lista.

```
lista = [1, 2, 3]

for numero in lista:
    print(numero)
```

A saída será:

```
1
2
3
```

Uma tupla (assim como uma lista) pode ser acessado pelo índice de seu elemento

```
tupla = ("John", "Doe", 40)

nome = tupla[0]
sobrenome = tupla[1]
idade = tupla[2]
```

Sendo assim temos:

```
>>> print(nome)
John
>>> print(sobrenome)
Doe
>>> print(idade)
40
```

### Juntanto dos dois

```
lista_com_tuplas = [("John", "Doe", 40), ("Joao", "Silva", 30)]

for tupla in lista_com_tuplas:
    nome = tupla[0]
    sobrenome = tupla[1]
    idade = tupla[2]
    print(f"{nome} {sobrenome} tem {idade} anos.")
```

Saída

```
John Doe tem 40 anos.
Joao Silva tem 30 anos.
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Ajudou sim, mas o que eu preciso é pegar somente um dos elementos de cada tupla e somar tds.... São várias Tuplas no qual eu preciso capturar 1 elemento de cada uma...

Comment: Consegue seguir a partir do que eu mostrei ou precisa de ajuda ainda?

Comment: Não consegui, Paulo. Fiz um for dentro de outro for, mas ele está iterando o primeiro item dentro da Tupla (que é uma Str), mas eu preciso que retorne o quinto elemento da Tupla, que é um Int.

Comment: Paulo, consegui agora!!! Fiz uma junção do que vc me respondeu e deu certo!!! Agradeço muito! Sou novo na programação e essa foi minha primeira postagem aqui e foi resolvido graças à sua contribuição!!! Agradeço imensamente sua ajuda!!! Abs e sucesso!

Comment: Boa @DarthGaino um passo por vez